# object class in python

Tags: python, object

In python the new style of class declaration is this:

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

what I don't understand is what is wrong with the old declaration,

```
class A:
    pass
```

more specifically, why they needed to add the base object class.Also,I want to know a little bit more about the object class in python,couldn't find any resource available on object class.

However, 
[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)
There's some answer over here,which talks about the rules but my specific question is what is the advantage of this declaration with object(Base class) on the declaration without the object.

Comment: New style classes can do more things; they support metaclasses, properties, class and static methods, etc. Subclasses of built-in types are new-style classes.

Comment: One of the answers there *tells you all this*:  [Old style and new style classes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19950198)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I would like to know more about object class,in java,The Object class has some methods which are useful,but a google search on object class in python does not seem to have any documentation on that.Don't they have any documentation on the object class?

Comment: The [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) tells you more than you want to know about what attributes and methods you can find on Python objects and custom classes.